$\Pi_n \circ T$ is continuous and T linear, them T is continuous.
For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\Pi_n: \ell^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functional defined by:
$$\Pi_n(\{x_i\})=x_n \quad \forall\{x_i\} \in \ell^1$$
and let $E$ be a Banach space. Prove that every linear operator $T: E \rightarrow \ell^1$ is continuous if and only if $\Pi_n \circ T$ is continuous from $E$ to $\mathbb{R}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
For the leftward implication, I did this:
If $\Pi_n \circ T$ is continuous, then it is bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ in particular. Therefore, there exists $M \geq 0$ such that $(\Pi_n \circ T)(x) \leq M \implies \Pi_n \circ T \in B(0,M) \implies T_x \in \Pi_n^{-1}(B(0,M))$. Since $\Pi_n$ is continuous (as demonstrated earlier), there exists $r>0$ such that $\Pi_n^{-1}(B(0,M)) \in B(0,r)$. Thus, $Tx \in B(0,r)$ and then $Tx$ is pointwise bounded. Since $E$ is a Banach space, by the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, we have that $T$ is continuous.
but I am not sure because of the hypotheses of the BS theorem, please I would appreciate your comments.
EDIT: Maybe $\Pi_n^{-1}(B(0,M)) \in B(0,r)$ is unbounded, because If we consider a ball, there are infinitely many points which have a projection to a point on its border.

It is basic courtesy in this site to accept and upvote answers which are helpful to you. That is the only way you reward the user who has taken time and devoted an effort to answer your question/query. You have not done so in any of your posts.

A lot of what you wrote here is not valid or uses notation in an invalid way. I suggest that you check the difference between the notational difference of writing $f\in A$ and $f(a)\in A$ if $f$ is a function taking values in a set $A$, as you appear to have made quite a few mistakes with that issue. Another issue is that you appear to be using the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to conclude that as $T$ is pointwise bounded, it is norm bounded. But what is required in the hypothesis is that the collection of linear operators you are looking at already consists of bounded linear operators, and the conclusion is that this collection of bounded linear operators is uniformly bounded. You can't apply the theorem to a single (possibly unbounded) linear operator in order to conclude that it is bounded.
As a suggestion for an approach to this question, note that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}(\Pi_{k}\circ T)(x) = T(x)$ for each $x\in E$. You can use this to show that $T$ is a pointwise limit of the sequence of bounded linear operators $(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\Pi_{k}\circ T))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then you can use the Banach-Steinhaus theorem to conclude that $T$ is also a bounded linear operator.
